# rails 3.1 relations between records from the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model called massmedia and this model belongs to company.

**We have companies:**  PRIME, JURNAL, ASMEDIA, MEDIA GROUP

**and massmedia:** PRIME TV, JURNAL TV, JURNAL FM, PUBLIKA TV

and the relation:

```
 Company                        TV Channel                    Company

1. **PRIME**        owner of   **PRIME TV**

2. **JURNAL**       owner of   **JURNAL TV**

3. **ASMEDIA**      owner of   **PUBLIKA TV**    owner of     **PRIME**

4. **MEDIA GROUP**                               owner of     **PRIME**
```

Now I got into problem where company **PRIME** is owned by **ASMEDIA** and **MEDIA GROUP** and that means I have to relate `company` to `company` and I am not sure if this can be done, even creating a new table for relation between 2 companies it's not good as I would need a table with 2 columns company_id of owned company and company_id of the one hwo owns it.

Any ideas how can I solve this? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I tried to create a scheme of what I tried to accomplish:

MediaGrup is the owner of the company Prime
and companies shareholder 1 and 2 are the owners of MediaGrup

so all of them: MediaGrup, Shareholder1 and 2 are in company model.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have relations between instances of the same classe. For example with `has_one` and `belongs_to` (it possible also with `has_many`, but your example shows no 0..n association) :

```
class MassMedia< ActiveRecord::Base   # the table "mass_medias" must have a column 'owner_id'
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'Company', :foreign_key => 'owner_id', :inverse_of => :mass_media
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base   # the table "companies" must have a column 'owner_id'
  has_one :mass_media, :inverse_of => :owner

  has_one :company, :inverse_of => :owner      
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'Company', :foreign_key => 'owner_id', :inverse_of => :company
end
```

Comment: as for more about this:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast